# python numpy.savetxt header has extra character #

Tags: python, numpy, header

I am using the following to save the numpy array x with a header:

```
np.savetxt("foo.csv", x, delimiter=",", header="ID,AMOUNT", fmt="%i")
```

However, if I open "foo.cv", the file looks like:

```
# ID,AMOUNT
21,100
52,120
63,29
:
```

There is an extra `#` character in the beginning of the header. Why is that and is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The header and footer text are added as comments. If you want to change the comment identifier, pass the `comments` option (the default is `#`):

```
np.savetxt("foo.csv", x, delimiter=",", header="ID,AMOUNT", 
           fmt="%i", comments='')
```

As [documented here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Answer (score 0):

it inserts the # because that line is a comment, and the default character for comments is the symbol #,

If you want to get rid of it, pass comments='' as option to savetxt.

```
numpy.savetxt('reference_vect_tool.00001.txt',riferimento,fmt='%.6f',header="reference", comments="")
```